# Unable to determine the meaning behind ~のみこと at the end of certain names

Tags: meaning

Examples include: 建速須佐之男命, 月読尊, and 神倭伊波礼琵古命/神日本磐余彦尊 (Here, I've been unable to merely identify the set of characters I'm to use, which is unfortunate.) So, what would this ~のみこと happen to mean?

And, does it work in any sort of fashion similar to modern names, id est, it signifying the first name? Or is it merely title?

Too, are all of these names merely that, one name, or do they have both a surname and a given name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

の is a possessive particle.

[尊{みこと}](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/211287/meaning/m0u/) is an honorific title/referral to a deity or a noble person:

> ［名］上代、神や人の呼び名の下につけた敬称。「…のみこと」の形で使う。「小碓 (おうす) の―」

Unless you were referring to a member of the Imperial family, みこと wouldn't be used.

Deities do not have family names. The Emperor neither.

What comes before is a proper name. Sometimes open to an interpretation, sometimes not.

In some cases みこと is translated as "the god who ...", in other "the god of ..." depending on the aforementioned meaning. The use of the full names of deities is pretty rare and limited to mythology or religious explanations of the name itself.

In case of human, "Lord" seems like a suitable English counterpart.

Comment: Thanks, I know that の is the genitive marker, I was just having trouble finding anything in regards to what I asked. Thanks again.